# Different ways to write NOT EXIST in SQL

Tags: sql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE t 
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    food VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO t (name, food) 
VALUES
('john', 'pizza'),
('john', 'cake'),
('andrew', 'pizza'),
('andrew', 'pizza'),
('andrew', 'pizza'),
('matt', 'pizza'),
('matt', 'pizza'),
('matt', 'burger'),
('david', 'cake'),
('david', 'pizza'),
('david', 'pizza'),
('elen', 'cake'),
('elen', 'pizza'),
('elen', 'donuts'),
('claire', 'cake'),
('claire', 'donuts'),
('claire', 'tacos'),
('john', 'pizza'),
('john', 'cake'),
('matt', 'apples'),
('matt', 'tacos');`
```

I have these two queries:

```
-- Query 1 : Select all rows/columns for names that ONLY like pizza.
select id, name, food
from prob1 as t1
where t1.food = 'pizza'
and not exists (select null
from prob1 as t2
where t2.name = t1.name
and t2.food != 'pizza')
order by 1;

--- Query 2:  Select all rows/columns for names that ONLY like pizza and cake
select id, name, food
from prob2 as t1
where t1.food in ('cake', 'pizza')
and not exists (select null
from prob2 as t2
where t2.name = t1.name
and t2.food not in ('cake', 'pizza'))
order by 1;
```

The problem is that sometimes I will be working on SQL platforms where the "NOT EXISTS" function will not be supported (e.g. I will get an error about correlated queries).

Are there some safe, general purpose alternatives I can use instead of NOT EXISTS  ... that will still accomplish the same thing?

E.g. Join Approach:

```
`-- Query 1
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.food
FROM t AS t1
LEFT JOIN t AS t2 ON t1.name = t2.name AND t2.food != 'pizza'
WHERE t1.food = 'pizza' AND t2.food IS NULL
ORDER BY 1;

-- Query 2
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.food
FROM t AS t1
LEFT JOIN t AS t2 ON t1.name = t2.name AND t2.food NOT IN ('cake', 'pizza')
WHERE t1.food IN ('cake', 'pizza') AND t2.food IS NULL
ORDER BY 1;
```

E.g. Group By/Having Approach:

```
-- Query 1
SELECT t.id, t.name, t.food
FROM t
WHERE t.name IN (
SELECT name
FROM t
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN food != 'pizza' THEN food END) = 0
)
AND t.food = 'pizza'
ORDER BY 1;

-- Query 2
SELECT t.id, t.name, t.food
FROM t
WHERE t.name IN (
SELECT name
FROM t
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN food NOT IN ('cake', 'pizza') THEN food END) = 0
)
AND t.food IN ('cake', 'pizza')
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: which database system are you using see [why should i tag my rdms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: also normalize your structure when you are at it

Comment: Every relational DB I’m aware of supports LEFT JOIN so that solution is probably the best one. BTW in your NOT EXISTS clause I wouldn’t SELECT NULL - use SELECT 1 (or any other actual value you want)

Comment: @nbk: I am using different database systems ... thats why I didn't want to tag a specific one

Comment: @NickW: Do you think the way I wrote the LEFT JOIN queries (i.e. Approach 1) are both correct? Are they accomplishing the goal of the original query?

Comment: I am curious, which RDBMS doesn't support `exists`?

Comment: Do your LEFT JOIN queries return the right result? If they do then they’re correct

Comment: This is much better than your prior question, thanks. I'd give the minor item of feedback that it is moderately better to repair old questions rather than repost, since an old deleted (and downvoted) question can slightly count against a question author (if one has a lot of them an automatic post limiter kicks in). But if you ask specific and focussed questions like this one in the future, you should be OK.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Exists and Not Exists could be performance costly.
If you insist on using  Exists / Not Exists then you could use something like here:

```sql
--    S a m p l e    D a t a :
CREATE TABLE t (id Number,
    a_name VARCHAR(50),
    food VARCHAR(50)
);
INSERT INTO t (id, a_name, food) VALUES
(1, 'john', 'pizza'), (2, 'john', 'cake'),
(3, 'andrew', 'pizza'), (4, 'andrew', 'pizza'), (5, 'andrew', 'pizza'),
(6, 'matt', 'pizza'), (7, 'matt', 'pizza'), (8, 'matt', 'burger'), (9, 'matt', 'apples'), (10, 'matt', 'tacos'), 
(11, 'david', 'cake'), (12, 'david', 'pizza'), (13, 'david', 'pizza'),
(14, 'elen', 'cake'), (15, 'elen', 'pizza'), (16, 'elen', 'donuts'),
(17, 'claire', 'cake'), (18, 'claire', 'donuts'), (19, 'claire', 'tacos'),
(20, 'john', 'pizza'), (21, 'john', 'cake');
```

```sql
--    O r a c l e     S Q L :
Select Distinct t1.*
From t t1
Inner Join t t2 ON(t2.a_name = t1.a_name)
Where Not Exists (Select 1 From t Where a_name = t2.a_name And food != 'pizza')
```

```sql
Select Distinct t1.*
From t t1
Inner Join t t2 ON(t2.a_name = t1.a_name And t2.food In('pizza', 'cake') )
Where Exists (Select 1 
              From t 
              Where a_name = t2.a_name 
              Group By a_name
              Having Count(Distinct food) = 2
             )
```

**A better alternative:**
You can have the same code answering different tasks just by changing the Where clause condition. To do it you'll need to create a list of distinct foods per a name. How to do it depends on database you are using. Here are the codes for Oracle sql, Postgresql and MySQL:

```sql
--    S Q L   -    O r a c l e :
Select t.* 
From t
Inner Join ( Select  Distinct 
                     a_name, 
                     LISTAGG(distinct food, ',') WITHIN GROUP (Order By food) Over(Partition By a_name) as food_list
             From t) f ON(f.a_name = t.a_name)
Where f.food_list = 'pizza';  -- for just pizza
Where f.food_list = 'cake,pizza';   -- for cake & pizza
Where InStr(f.food_list, 'pizza') = 0;  -- for no pizza at all
Where InStr(f.food_list, 'pizza') = 0 and position('cake' in f.food_list) = 0; -- for no pizza and no cake
```

```sql
--    S Q L    -   P o s t g r e s q l
Select t.* 
From t
Inner Join ( Select  a_name, string_agg(distinct food, ',') as food_list
             From t
             Group By a_name ) f ON(f.a_name = t.a_name)
Where f.food_list = 'pizza';  -- for just pizza
Where f.food_list = 'cake,pizza';  -- for cake & pizza
Where position('pizza' in f.food_list) = 0;  -- for no pizza at all
Where position('pizza' in f.food_list) = 0 and position('cake' in f.food_list) = 0;      -- for no pizza and no cake
```

```sql
--    S Q L    -   M y S Q L
Select t.* 
From t
Inner Join ( Select  a_name, 
                     group_concat(Distinct food separator ', ') as food_list
             From t
             Group By a_name) f ON(f.a_name = t.a_name)
Where f.food_list = 'pizza';  -- for just pizza
Where f.food_list = 'cake,pizza';   -- for cake & pizza
Where InStr(f.food_list, 'pizza') = 0;  -- for no pizza at all
Where InStr(f.food_list, 'pizza') = 0 and position('cake' in f.food_list) = 0; -- for no pizza and no cake
```

This is usefull for different possible queries and easy to maintain. The subquery could be declared as a CTE, too, making it even more readable and maintainable...

Comment: @ d_r : thank you so much ... is it possible to do this without group_concat?

Comment: BTW is the JOIN approach and the GROUP BY approach I used correct?

Comment: @pnaxso Just posted exists and not exists version...

Comment: thank you ... I feel really bad for asking you so many questions. I accepted your answer .... I would upvote too but I dont have enough points

Comment: can you please comment on my JOIN approach and my GROUP BY approach? Are they correct?

Comment: @pnaxso Checked just for query 1 both of your aproaches. They work, just have in mind that the code will be (sooner or later) maintained by someone else. Try to use identation in the codee for readability and maintainability. This is not about using joins or groupings (it never is)  as there are always many ways to do it - as you could see in my answers. For just exists or not answers - the 1st doesn't need grouping at all while the 2nd one does (it could be written without it, though. but with a lot more code).  Try to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: "Exists and Not Exists could be performance costly" not with modern optimizers, asit is optimized into an anti-join. The primary performance issue here would have been the double join on the same table.